# different AWK flavors with diff smallest double value

Tags: awk, double, underflow

there appears to be discrepancy regarding what each flavor of awk considers the smallest figure before it underflows to zero:

> mawk 1.3.4 | mawk 1.9.9.6 | macos built-in nawk 
> all say `2^-1074`
> or `4.94 x 10^-324`

> but gawk 5.1.0 (w/o activating GMP or MPFR) ends at 
> `2^-1023`
> or `1.11 x 10^-308`

which one is the IEEE 754-compliant one here ?

=====================================

ps : thanks for everyone's replies. i found 2 workarounds with gawk :

```
exp(-log(2)*(1024-1+52-1))
```

or

```
2^-(1024-1) * 2^-(52-1)
```

- i typed it out more verbosely to make it easier to follow along regarding how the figures were derived. for shorter hand,they're

> `exp(-1074 * log(2))` 
>   `(2^-51) * (2^-1023)`

Answer (score 2):

**IEEE-compliance:** all awk versions are IEEE compliant and can represent normal and subnormal numbers in double-precision or in the precision defined by the user (cfr. [Daweo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084088/8344060)). In case of GNU-awk you can see denormal numbers as:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (2^-1023)/2}'
5.56268e-309
```

Furthermore, IEEE-754 states that:

> The default exception handling for underflow shall always deliver a rounded result. The method for detecting tininess does not affect the rounded result delivered, which might be zero, subnormal, or *±b<sup>emin</sup>*.

In case of GNU awk, the underflow is returned as a zero value in case of 2^-1024.

**GNU awk and `2^-1024`:** So why does GNU awk return `0.0` when computing `2^-1024` but it can compute `(2^-1023)/2`?

When looking in the source-code, you find that if the power is a negative integer, it is computed via it's inverse (see code snippet below). This means that GNU awk computes 2^-1024 as 1.0/2^1024. But 2^1024 cannot be represented as a double precision number. The largest double-precision number is `2^1023 × (1 + (1 − 2−52)) < 2^1024`. Hence, the exponent overflows leading to zero for the computation of 2^-1024.

```
static AWKNUM
calc_exp_posint(AWKNUM x, long n)
{
    AWKNUM mult = 1;

    while (n > 1) {
        if ((n % 2) == 1)
            mult *= x;
        x *= x;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return mult * x;
}

/* calc_exp --- calculate x1^x2 */

AWKNUM
calc_exp(AWKNUM x1, AWKNUM x2)
{
    long lx;

    if ((lx = x2) == x2) {      /* integer exponent */
        if (lx == 0)
            return 1;
        return (lx > 0) ? calc_exp_posint(x1, lx)
                : 1.0 / calc_exp_posint(x1, -lx);
    }
    return (AWKNUM) pow((double) x1, (double) x2);
}
```

Comment: ahh thanks everyone. i found 2 ways to get gawk to give me that lowest value :

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto How did you get the lowest value? An extra division, a combination of log and exp (`awk 'BEGIN{printf "%25.17e\n", exp(-1074*log(2))}'`) or something else? Furthermore, If you like any of the answers, consider upvoting and/or accepting any of the answers. ([Someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: i've amended by answer above but here you go - this is the verbose approach to showcase where the 1074 came from : exp(-log(2)*(1024-1+52-1)) . another way is 2^-(1024-1) * 2^-(52-1) or even 2^(1-1024) * 2^(1-52). thanks for your responses ^^^

Answer (score 1):

According to [GNU AWK manual - Setting precision](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Setting-precision.html)

> `gawk` uses a global working precision; it does not keep track of the
> precision or accuracy of individual numbers. Performing an arithmetic
> operation or calling a built-in function rounds the result to the
> current working precision. The default working precision is 53 bits,
> which you can modify using the predefined variable `PREC`. You can also
> set the value to one of the predefined case-insensitive strings shown
> in Table 16.4, to emulate an IEEE 754 binary format.

**Table 16.4**: Predefined precision strings for `PREC`

| PREC | IEEE 754 binary format |
| --- | --- |
| "half" | 16-bit half precision |
| "single" | Basic 32-bit single precision |
| "double" | Basic 64-bit double precision |
| "quad" | Basic 128-bit quardruple precision |
| "oct" | 256-bit octuple precision |

As you might deduce from above default setting (53-bit) is none of IEEE 754. You need to set `PREC` to one of above if you need behavior compliant with IEEE 754.